# plot a dataframe as a line graph in R

Tags: r, ggplot2, line-plot

I have a dataset like this one, and I would like to plot a line graph like the one in the image which I did in excel, but I want to choose the colors.

[excel graph](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SvqXu.gif)

```
df <- as.data.frame(matrix(runif(n=590, min=1, max=2), nrow=32))
df$subjects <- c(1:32)
names(df) <- 
c('A','B','C','D','E','F','G','H','I','L','M','N','O','P','Q','R','S','T','V','SUBJECT')
```

Comment: try getting the basic plot up, then ask for guidance coloring it

Comment: ggplot2 works most fluidly with "long," aka "tidy" data, where each row is an observation and each column is a variable. If your series are measuring the same thing, but are in different columns, you'll almost always want to reshape first, e.g. by using `library(tidyr); df %>% pivot_longer(-SUBJECT) %>% ggplot(aes(name, value, color = SUBJECT))`    https://r4ds.had.co.nz/tidy-data.html